# Functional Programming using python for extracting consecutive capitalized words

Tags: python

I am now using python to extract consecutive capitalized words (at least two) in a text.

For example, there is a sentence

> Hollywood is a neighborhood in the central region of Los Angeles.

Then the expected output should be

> Los Angeles

I am trying to do this thing in a **functional programming** way.

```
import itertools
import string
import operator

text = "Take any tram, U-bahn or bus which stops at Düsseldorf Hauptbahnhof (HBF). Leave the station via the main exit Konrad Adenauer Platz, you will see trams and buses in front of the station. Walk up Friedrich Ebert Straße turning right into the third street which is the Oststraße."

def fold(it):
    def fold_impl(x, y):
        return itertools.starmap(operator.and_, zip(x, itertools.islice(y, 1, None)))
    return fold_impl(*itertools.tee(it))

def unfold(it):
    def unfold_impl(x, y):
        return itertools.starmap(operator.or_, zip(itertools.chain(x, [False]), itertools.chain([False], y)))
    return unfold_impl(*itertools.tee(it))

def ngrams(it, n):
    return it if n <= 1 else unfold(ngrams(fold(it), n - 1))

def ngrams_idx(it, n):
    return (sorted(x[0] for x in g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(enumerate(ngrams(it, n)), key=lambda x: x[1]) if k)

def booleanize(text_vec):
    return map(lambda x: x[0] in string.ascii_uppercase, text_vec)

def ngrams_phrase(text_vec, n):
    def word(text_vec, idx):
        return ' '.join(map(lambda i: text_vec[i], idx))
    return [word(text_vec, idx) for idx in ngrams_idx(booleanize(text_vec), n)]
```

But I think I am making it a little bit too complicated, is there any simpler way to deal with this question using **functional programming**?

Comment: How do you use this functions? You never call any of them with `text`.

Comment: @LutzHorn call the last function ngrams_phrase, and the parameter should be the text after splitting and the minimum number of consecutive capitalized words, btw, thx for the editing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this:

```
from itertools import takewhile

text = "Take any tram, U-bahn or bus which stops at Düsseldorf Hauptbahnhof (HBF). Leave the station via the main exit Konrad Adenauer Platz, you will see trams and buses in front of the station. Walk up Friedrich Ebert Straße turning right into the third street which is the Oststraße."

def take_upper(text):
    it = iter(text.split())
    return [[i]+list(takewhile(lambda x: x[0].isupper(), it)) for i in it if i[0].isupper()]

def remove_singles(text_uppers):
    return [l for l in text_uppers if len(l) > 1]

remove_singles(take_upper(text))
```

Comment: Thx, but I still have a question: is there any way to avoid list concatenation?

Comment: You could write another simple function that takes `[i]` and the list generated by `takewhile`, merges them (by calling `list.extend`) and returns a new list.

Answer (score 1):

Is not really a good practice in python, but the shortest way is to reduce the splited text:

```
p = "Hollywood is a neighborhood in the central region of Los Angeles.".split()
t, _ = reduce(lambda (l, v), x: (l+[v, x], x) if v[0].isupper() and x[0].isupper() else (l, x), p, ([], "a"))
['Los', 'Angeles.']
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the entry call would be `ngram_phrase(text.split(), 2)` and OP is looking for *all the occurrence of phrases whose number of consecutive capitalized initials is at least 2*, e.g. running the code snippet together with `text` would result `["Düsseldorf Hauptbahnhof", "Konrad Adenauer Platz", "Friedrich Ebert Straße"]`.

Answer (score 1):

I would have provided on of the answers above but they were already provided! So I wrote the following function to allow you to see the flow.

```
def find_proper(text):
    text = text.rstrip().split(' ')
    proper = []
    data, cnt, pos, str = [x[0].isupper() for x in text], 0, 0, ''
    while True:
        if pos == len(text):
            if cnt > 1:
                proper.append(str.rstrip())
            break
        if data[pos]:
            cnt += 1
            str += text[pos]+' '
        else:
            if cnt > 1:
                proper.append(str.rstrip())
            str = ''
            cnt = 0
        pos += 1
    return proper
print find_proper(text)
```